# Can't read a .CSV file in Spyder (Python 3.6) and it's not a path or character issue

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm new in python, I'm learning it so, please, try to be simple when answer me =) thx since now! I'm using Spyder (Python 3.6) and trying to run these lines:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(r'Legumes.csv')
df
```

But, I'm having every possible kind of error, and trust me, I read and tried a lot of solutions but, none seemed to fix my problem.
First, the file "Legumes" does exist, and it is in the same folder than the spyder file (.py one).

1-I inicially tried run the lines using a relative path, since the two files are in the same folder, spyder returned me this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: File b'Legumes.csv' does not exist
```

2-Then I tried use a full path, but, I've got this error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

3-Then, I tried insert the "r", before the path, so python would understand that this string means a path, and, I've got this:

```
FileNotFoundError: File b'Legumes.csv' does not exist
```

Note: I made sure of using no invalid caracters in the path and in the file (.csv), like ´, ^, or ~. I also tried use "r" in full and relative path (as shown in my paste above), the error message was the same.

4-I tried rename the files and run, nothing changed. Tried also re-load .py file to discart some location issues, nothing again...

The most irritating thing is, it works only for the first time, I wrote it last friday and worked just fine, I just saved and closed. Today when I got back to work it just don't run anymore!! I'm blowing up with this!!!!

Comment: If your full path is with ``\`` change it to `/`

Comment: Are you on windows or Mac?

Comment: @skarchmit Yeah i am on windows, that's how you do it on windows but i don't know about Mac

Comment: "and it is in the same folder than the spyder file (.py one)" That isn't what matters. If you are going to use a relative path then it has to be at that path *relative to your working directory*. If you want to figure out exactly what your working directory is, in the same environment (heck, in the same script), do `import os; print(os.getcwd())`

Answer (score 0):

Your path needs to be absolute

On  **Mac / Linux**

```
  ‘/path/to/legumes.csv’
```

Pro-Tip: You can get the full path by right clicking on the file while holding option key, then select “copy legumes.csv as pathname”

On **Windows**

```
  r’C:\\path\to\legumes.csv’
```

The reason we have the r is because we want it to be interpreted as a raw string, not a string that we are trying to escape with \ characters
Some of these escape characters are  \t for a tab, \n for a new line and so forth. Any another Other Unrecognizable Escape Character will throw you that error

```
 codec can't decode bytes
```

Pro-Tip: you can get the full path by right clicking on the file while holding shift key and then selecting “copy as path”

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different formats you could use for the path to the file, including the following:

```
# Absolute path
dataframe = pd.read_csv(r'd:\development\data.csv')
dataframe = pd.read_csv('d:\development\data.csv')
dataframe = pd.read_csv('d:/development/data.csv')
```

If you'd like to use a relative path, that's also possible.

```
# Relative path
dataframe = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

However, it seems that the relative path is not relative to the current file, but relative to the working directory.  In Spyder 5, you can set that typing/browsing with the directory selection tool at the top of the IDE.